# How to compare a value in one pandas column using a value in another without getting 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, ambiguous

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
    ID       Year
0   509     2023.0
1   216     1998.0
2   193     1957.0
```

I want to be able to use the value of the ID parameter to be a be able to compare the Year parameter to the current year and evaluate if its true.

For example, this is the code I have:

```
if df.loc[df["ID"] == 509]["Year"] == 2023.0:
   print("The ID belongs to this year")
```

But right now I am currently getting this error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think it has to do with the fact that I am comparing a series of values with a single float value but I am having trouble fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
id_num = 509
year = 2023

if (df['ID'].eq(id_num) & df['Year'].eq(year)).any():
    print('The ID belongs to this year')
```